# Grab numbers after a colon?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, int, formatter

I have a time string that looks like this: `5:34 pm`.  I want to grab the `5`, put it in a variable, and grab the `34` and put it in a variable.  Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have fine literal answers to your question, but if you're trying to parse a time, see -[NSDateFormatter dateFromString:].

Comment: @Ken  I tried using it, but for my needs simply parsing the string was all I needed.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSArray *splitString = [timeString componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
if ([splitString count] > 1 {
    NSString *hours = [splitString objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *minutes = [splitString objectAtIndex:1];
}
else {
    //improperly formatted string
}
```

Comment: Beautiful!  Just what I needed.  Thank you, will accept answer as soon as it's availible.

Comment: No problem! I remember looking for this method way back. :-)

Answer (score 6):

Watch out for the NSString technique listed above. If your string is missing a colon you'll crash getting objectAtIndex:1. (I'd comment on it but I lack sufficient rep.)

This should be a little more robust.

```
int hours, minutes;
if (2 == sscanf([timeString UTF8String], "%d:%d", &hours, &minutes))
{
    // congratulations, you did it
}
else
{
    // the string was malformed
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I should go with a C-style function or a Objective-C style method?

Comment: Pretty sure it'll always have a colon.

Comment: also, even in the other method it's easy to check for malformed euqations: just check that splitString.count>1. Also, if you need more control I recommend you look at `NSScanner`.

Comment: If there's one thing I've learned, it's that you never know when malformed inputs will strike. It's always better to check, even if you think it will never be wrong, than to save one line of code and then crash in the field because you are accessing off the end of an array.